Moving to another job after applying for Niederlassungserlaubnis
I applied for the Permanent Settlement Permit (Niederlassungserlaubnis) 2 months ago in Munich Germany, and am still waiting for the appointment. The case officer tells me that it can take up to 3 months. However, in the meanwhile I have the possibility of getting another job offer and have to accept it.
Would it be OK if I accepted that offer? Would that affect the process for my permanent settlement permit?

I had the same situation. I was asked to wait until the probation period at my new company was completed.

Welcome to Expatriates! While you do seem to have a good-faith effort to answer this question (thanks!), it's a bit unclear if you're timeline actually matches the OP's timeline, and who told you to 'wait'. Could you elaborate this answer, not only for the OP, but for the sake of others who might face a similar or identical situation?
